# The covering transformation is determined by its value at the base point

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Consider the group of covering transformations of the (based) covering map $p:(E,e_0)\to (B,b_0)$. On p. 488 Munkres writes that a covering transformation $h$ is uniquely determined by its value at $e_0$, but I don't see any explanation of this. Why is this so?

Comment: Could you add the chapter name and theorem name/number if any? I have something entirely different in my copy of Munkres.

Comment: @Boshu "Classification of Covering Spaces", it's from the definition before Lemma 81.1 (in the US edition) or Lemma 76.1 (in Indian edition). [Both are second editions.]

Comment: I had some trouble locating it in Munkres, but unless I am mistaken, this should follow from what is called the universal lifting property. You should be able to find in the the first chapter of Hatcher in the section under covering spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not true for arbitrary covering maps (consider for example the projection $p : B \times F \to B$, where $F$ is discrete). However, if we assume that $E$ is path connected, then we can argue as follows:

In Lemma 54.1 Munkres establishes the unique path lifting property for covering maps. Here is a corollary:

Let $X$ be path connected and $f : X \to B$ be a map. If $\tilde{f}_0, \tilde{f}_1 : X \to E$ are lifts of $f$ such that $\tilde{f}_0(x) = \tilde{f}_1(x)$ for some $x \in X$, then $\tilde{f}_0 = \tilde{f}_1$.

Proof. Let $y \in X$ and $u : [0,1] \to X$ be a path from $x$ to $y$. Then $\tilde{f}_0u$ and $\tilde{f}_1u$ are lifts of the path $fu : [0,1] \to B$ which agree at $t = 0$. Hence they also agree at $t = 1$. This means $\tilde{f}_0(y) = (\tilde{f}_0u)(1) = (\tilde{f}_1u)(1) = \tilde{f}_1(y)$.

Now any covering transformation is a lift of $p : E \to B$. Hence if two covering transformations agree at $e_0$, then they are identical if $E$ is path connected.